# If one gives a food gift on Shabbos, does the one who receives it need to use it on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sources-mekorot, food, gifts

The Halacha is that one may give a food gift to another on Shabbos. (See [Dose of Halacha](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/gifts-on-shabbos.html) for more details).
If I give a bottle of wine, do they need to open it on Shabbos, or can they choose to keep it for after Shabbos?

Please state the source for your answer - other than from the link above

Comment: In your link it clearly says "One who receives a bottle of wine, for example, is not obligated to open it that day."

Answer (score -2):

According to [this article](http://kesher.org.uk/giving-gifts-on-shabbos/), it seems that it **is** required. Furthermore, before you gave the gift, you would have to verify that the recipient would be using it on Shabbat.

> If it is le-tzorech Shabbos, i.e. necessary for Shabbos use. This is
> actually a broad heter, as many gifts you may want to give, e.g. wine,
> liqueur, chocolate, cake, etc can definitely be construed as
> le-tzorech Shabbos. **The weakness here is that they are not actually
> necessary for Shabbos use, as your hosts likely planned sufficient
> food and drink without taking into account the gift that you will
> bring**. So it may be useful for Shabbos, but is it necessary for
> Shabbos?

In other words, it seems that the responsibility is more on you prior to giving the gift, but the recipient also must follow up with the action of using it. Don't give a bottle of wine that you think the recipient won't use. Better, call before Shabbat and verify if they will use it.

(In this context "tzorech" is translated as "necessary". It's a loose translation, as it seems that they mean using it even if the recipient feels that, technically, they don't "need" it. E.g. - even if the recipient says, "It was unnecessary for you to bring it", but they use it anyway, that's fine. In other words, the act of using it makes it "needed".)

The article suggests work-arounds, but I don't think they are relevant to answering the question.

---

See @AvrohomYitzchok's comment, below. I can't access the link, now, but I feel his answer is even stronger than mine, and I recommend that he posts his comment as an answer, so you can give him the points and / or bounty!

Comment: See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2179 -- throwing out the premise of the question doesn't make a good answer if the question is still valid.

Comment: The question MAY be valid. It's invalid based on 1 opinion.

Comment: So the question is according to the opinion that holds like that.

Comment: That article talks about using an eruv. 
[Here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/700456/jewish/What-Is-an-Eruv.htm) it says that 

items which will only be used after Shabbat also cannot be carried on Shabbat, even within the eruv.

Comment: I've read the linked article. It doesn't answer the question at all, sorry

Answer (score -2):

There are two problems.

1) A derivative of the prohibition of commercial transactions (see source quoted below by @DanF (thank you)).

A way out of this problem is where the gift is for the need of Shabbos. And that is where the question arises whether the intended recipient will use it on Shabbos or not. And if he will not use it, is it allowed to have given it to him.

In [The Halachos shown by Rabbi Ostroff to
HaGaon HaRav Moshe Sternbuch, shlita](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbos3_33.htm) he says,

> I think though that if one brings a good bottle of wine and it is
>   intended to be opened at the meal then it may be given on
>   Shabbos l’chatchila because it is needed for the sake of Shabbos.

I once heard that even if it is not opened, it should still be allowed as the recipient will still have benefit from it on Shabbos in that he knows he has not depleted his stock of wine  (because  the gift makes up for the wine he served).

2) The comments given in (1) above apply when there has been no use of an eruv to transport the gift. But where an eruv is going to be used, we need to remember that as [this article](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/700456/jewish/What-Is-an-Eruv.htm) says:

> ... items which will only be used after Shabbat also cannot be carried
>   on Shabbat, even within the eruv.

and so if the eruv has been used the wine will need to be drunk on Shabbos.

Comment: You've not actually answered the question. You haven't provided a source to explain whether if an item is given it must be used.

Comment: @user5303 I meant to be understood that: if an eruv is used to transport the gift then the gift must be used and the source is the link referred to by the words in my attempted answer "this article".